# Refining Re Search

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I need help regarding regular expression.

```
line = "nadya carson nadya@gmail.com wxwwwgg 1235454 wmsiqrr 9gag2cm 9.9%"
```

I have lines like one above from which I need to extract the string after email,in the above example '**wxwwwgg**' . The string comes exactly after email and before numbers.

I tried:

```
>>> a = re.search(r'\s\w+\s\d',line)
>>> a
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0271F640>
>>> a.group()
' wxwwwgg 1'
```

Isn't there any way where I can omit the numeric character in my matchgroup.? In the above example can I get only 'wxwwwgg' with the help of any search patterns used in regular expression instead of `r'\s\w+\s\d'`
Thanks.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this. They make sure a (sub)match is *possible* at the current position, without making those submatches part of the actual match:

```
a = re.search(r'(?<=\s)\w+(?=\s\d)', line)
```